# Fetching entities with relations in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities in my Core Data database `Person` and `Photo` a `Person` has a `To-Many` relationship with `Photo` and `Photo` has a reverse relationship with `Person` `(Person<-->>Photo)`. I load some initial data for my app off a .plist in the following manner:

```
-(void)populateDataStorage{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FakeData" ofType:@"plist"];

    if(path){
        NSArray *plistData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [plistData objectEnumerator];

        NSArray *personResults;

        Photo *photo;
        Person *person;

        id currItem = [enumerator nextObject];

        while (currItem != nil) {
            photo = (Photo *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:[flickrFetcher managedObjectContext]];

            photo.name = [currItem objectForKey:@"name"];
            photo.path = [currItem objectForKey:@"path"];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", [currItem objectForKey:@"user"]];

            personResults = [flickrFetcher fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:predicate];

            if ([personResults count] > 0) {
                person = [personResults objectAtIndex:0];
            } 
            else {
                person = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[flickrFetcher managedObjectContext]];
                person.name = [currItem objectForKey:@"user"];
            }

            photo.person = person;
            [person addPhotosObject:photo];

            NSLog(@"Photo %@ added for user %@", photo.name, person.name);

            currItem = [enumerator nextObject];
        }

        [plistData release];

    }

}
```

Everything loads properly. Then I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the `Person` and load a `UITableView` and it all works. When the user clicks on a cell that belongs to a user I have to load another `UITableView` with the selected Person's Photos, so I do the following in my UITableViewController for my Photo's table view:

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", person];
        self.fetchedResultsController = [[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Photo" withPredicate:predicate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in my `viewDidLoad` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    for(Photo *photo in person.photos){
        NSLog(@"Photo %@ belongs to %@", photo.name, person.name);
    }

    NSLog(@"Photo count %d", [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);
}
```

The count is giving me 0, i never get the Person's Photos but I know they are properly saved because they all print out for the passed in `Person`. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT

Utility method for getting the `NSFetchedResultsController` in my `FlickrFetcher` class:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Add a predicate if we're filtering by user name
    if (predicate) {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return [fetchedResultsController autorelease];
}
```

My own `NSFetchedResultsController` created in my `UITableViewController`:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:[flickFetcher managedObjectContext]];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:descriptor, nil];

    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", person];

    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[flickFetcher managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    [request release];
    [descriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [fetchedResultsController autorelease];
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see anything offhand.  I'd want to insert a save on the context after I inserted all the test data.  (And not insert it next time around.)

One comment:

```
photo.person = person;
[person addPhotosObject:photo];
```

this is redundant.  A relationship that is modeled with a reverse relationship in core data will correctly set the reverse relationship, if you set the other.  So, only one of these lines is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I managed to retrieve the Photos from the context which is weird because all I did was create my own fetched results controller that doesn't differ from the utility method I had before, but now the table cells aren't set, cellForRowAtIndex is never called for some reason, I will update the code to show both fetchedResultsControllers.

Comment: no cellForRowAtIndex: = no tableView.dataSource, or numberOfRowsInSection = 0

Comment: was the numberOfRowsInSection deal, that did the trick. Notice any difference in my fetchedResultsControllers? Besides the ascending parameter